# How to attach components to root component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have made a `courses.component.ts` component and now I want to add it `app.component.ts` but it does not work. Why?

In app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>{{ mainheading }}</h1><courses></courses>',
})

export class AppComponent {
    mainheading = "My Angular App";
}
```

In courses.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CourseService} from './course.service';

@Component({
    selector:'courses',
    template: `<h2>Courses</h2> {{title}}
    <ul> 
    <li *ngFor="#c of courses">{{c}} </li>
    </ul>`
    providers: [CourseService]
})

export class CoursesComponent {
    title: string ="The title of courses";
    courses; 

    constructor (courseService:CourseService){
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses(); 
    }
}
```

In course.service.ts :

```
export class CourseService {
    getCourses():string[]{
        return ["Course1","Course2","Course3"];
    }
}
```

Why is my code not working? I am using Angular in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Could you expand on "not working"? Have you included the new component in the appropriate module?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have done everything properly.

Comment: Well then it must be working. You're complaining it's not, so clearly you haven't. Give a [mcve]. Note you seem to have at least one missing comma, which an error somewhere should be telling you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe As soon as I add `directives:[CoursesComponent]` in component decorator it starts working why so.

Comment: Because you apparently *didn't* provide your component in the module, despite your claim in reply to my first comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry I couldn't get you I checked the docs of angular but it doesn't have `directive` array check docs -> https://angular.io/api/core/Component

Comment: Yes, I believe that's deprecated in recent versions. *Put your decorations in the module*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please tell me why does it displays Courses1,Courses2,Courses3, as soon as I add this line `directives:[CoursesComponent]` in `@Component` decorator. That's my question.

Comment: That's not the question you've written above. Please read the Angular tutorial and the relevant docs for your version (https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html) which will explain the DI system, why you need to provide your component definitions and therefore why that works. If you *still* have a question after that research, [edit] to make it clear what precisely it is, following the guidance at [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for helping I spent half an hour on searching docs for decorator meta-data `directive` as I am new to angular 2 can you please give me a link to docs where I can see how to make modules and add component in it.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @jonrsharpe English is my 2nd language can you please frame the question accordingly as I am finding it difficult.

Comment: What version of Angular are you actually using? Looks like it's beta version, so are you using a beta version of Angular?

Comment: @AJT_82 what is beta version ? Is there any other version of angular ? I am using angular 2

Comment: Well beta is like beta usually refers to "not finished version". Beta versions are really outdated. At least use angular  2 ***final***, which is almost a year old too (!!!). We are currently on version 4.x.x which is also what the official tutorial is having. Check the official tuto instead of some old tutorial you are running through. Just like linked before: https://angular.io/tutorial Here's change logs to follow too: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: 4.3.0 was [released yesterday](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/angular-43-now-available.html). 2.0 final was released in September 2016. Continuing to use beta/release candidate versions from before that is a very bad idea.